# Cannot access my Ubuntu Samba share from my Windows 11 laptop - "The username or password is incorrect"

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I have an Ubuntu machine running in my house, and it has a few samba shares. I use it with my Windows 10 Gaming PC and it works flawlessly.
However, with my Lenovo, it doesn't. Actually, it used to work, however when I installed a fresh Windows 10 install, I couldn't make it work. Recently, after many months of not having it working, I decided to fresh install Windows 11, However it still gives the same error.

[image]

I can access the Ubuntu machine using SSH from the CMD (or even SFTP using filezilla for that matter).

Here's the content of my smb.conf

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
# errors.

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
protocol = SMB3
client ntlmv2 auth = yes

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

log level = 3

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
;   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the
# SAMR RPC pipe.
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[DISK1]
path = /media/DISK1
valid users = sambauser
read only = no
browseable = yes

[DISK2]
path = /media/DISK2
valid users = sambauser
read only = no

[DISK3]
path = /media/DISK3
valid users = sambauser
read only = no
```

And here's the samba log when I try to connect:

```
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.631326,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1340(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.631456,  3] ../source3/smbd/process.c:1959(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 288 (0 toread)
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.631854,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:290(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_11
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635684,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635698,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635704,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635715,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635721,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635731,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635737,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635742,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635748,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635753,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635759,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635764,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.635770,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.638084,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe2088297
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640206,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:454(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[sambauser] domain=[MicrosoftAccount] workstation=[LENOVO-YOGA-730] len1=24 len2=238
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640237,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3866(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640267,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:549(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640308,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2780(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640358,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640421,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640453,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[print$]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640474,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[WD_12TB]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640496,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Seagate_8TB]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640515,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Seagate_5TB]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640535,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[TorrentBox]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640555,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[WD_EXT]"
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640581,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1615(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640594,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [MicrosoftAccount]\[sambauser]@[LENOVO-YOGA-730] with the new password interface
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640600,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [MicrosoftAccount]\[sambauser]@[LENOVO-YOGA-730]
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640650,  3] ../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'sambauser' in passdb.
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640660,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:332(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [sambauser] -> [sambauser] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640681,  2] ../auth/auth_log.c:760(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [MicrosoftAccount]\[sambauser] at [Sun, 10 Apr 2022 11:28:26.640676 -03] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER] workstation [LENOVO-YOGA-730] remote host [ipv4:192.168.0.103:51309] mapped to [MicrosoftAccount]\[sambauser]. local host [ipv4:192.168.0.136:445]
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640732,  2] ../auth/auth_log.c:220(log_json)
  JSON Authentication: {"timestamp": "2022-04-10T11:28:26.640702-0300", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "status": "NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.0.136:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.0.103:51309", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "MicrosoftAccount", "clientAccount": "sambauser", "workstation": "LENOVO-YOGA-730", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": "(NULL SID)", "mappedAccount": "sambauser", "mappedDomain": "MicrosoftAccount", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": "(NULL SID)", "passwordType": "NTLMv2"}}
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640749,  2] ../auth/gensec/spnego.c:605(gensec_spnego_server_negTokenTarg)
  SPNEGO login failed: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.640779,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3139(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_sesssetup.c:134
[2022/04/10 11:28:26.642716,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:244(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

Log from my other Windows computer that I can successfully access the samba shares:

```
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.820691,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1340(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.820827,  3] ../source3/smbd/process.c:1959(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 256 (0 toread)
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.821334,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:290(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_11
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825028,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825043,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825050,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825056,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825062,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825068,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825074,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825079,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825085,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825096,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825102,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825107,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.825113,  3] ../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.833027,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe2088297
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.916945,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:454(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[sambauser] domain=[DESKTOP-087T07G] workstation=[DESKTOP-087T07G] len1=24 len2=238
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.917077,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3866(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.917214,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:549(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.917487,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2780(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.917799,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1823(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918090,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918231,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[print$]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918328,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[WD_12TB]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918427,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Seagate_8TB]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918518,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[Seagate_5TB]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918609,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[TorrentBox]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918700,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2797(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[WD_EXT]"
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918818,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1615(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918872,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [DESKTOP-087T07G]\[sambauser]@[DESKTOP-087T07G] with the new password interface
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.918903,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [DESKTOP-087T07G]\[sambauser]@[DESKTOP-087T07G]
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.919396,  3] ../source3/passdb/lookup_sid.c:1759(get_primary_group_sid)
  Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for sambauser
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.920064,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:256(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  auth_check_ntlm_password: sam_ignoredomain authentication for user [sambauser] succeeded
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927176,  3] ../auth/auth_log.c:760(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [DESKTOP-087T07G]\[sambauser] at [Sun, 10 Apr 2022 14:46:02.927134 -03] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [DESKTOP-087T07G] remote host [ipv4:192.168.0.112:64072] became [UBUNTU]\[sambauser] [S-1-5-21-2092467104-2299291568-701835823-1000]. local host [ipv4:192.168.0.136:445]
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927432,  3] ../auth/auth_log.c:220(log_json)
  JSON Authentication: {"timestamp": "2022-04-10T14:46:02.927308-0300", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 0}, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.0.136:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.0.112:64072", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "DESKTOP-087T07G", "clientAccount": "sambauser", "workstation": "DESKTOP-087T07G", "becameAccount": "sambauser", "becameDomain": "UBUNTU", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-2092467104-2299291568-701835823-1000", "mappedAccount": "sambauser", "mappedDomain": "DESKTOP-087T07G", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": "(NULL SID)", "passwordType": "NTLMv2"}}
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927499,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:314(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [sambauser] -> [sambauser] -> [sambauser] succeeded
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927558,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927586,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe2088215
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927663,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_sign.c:509(ntlmssp_sign_reset)
  NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.927690,  3] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:69(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe2088215
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.928215,  3] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:559(finalize_local_nt_token)
  Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.928314,  3] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:591(finalize_local_nt_token)
  Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
[2022/04/10 14:46:02.938326,  3] ../source3/smbd/password.c:144(register_homes_share)
  Adding homes service for user 'sambauser' using home directory: '/home/sambauser'
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that the username "sambauser" has capital letters not tried by Samba? E.g., it will try "Sambauser" automatically, but not "SambaUser".

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for the reply! It's not the username the problem. I typed exactly how it is and no luck. I also can access this samba share using my other computer (and also my android smartphone) and I use the same credentials.
I was thinking maybe it's the workgroup, so I tried typing "WORKGROUP\sambauser" in the username field, but same problem...

Comment: What is the exact syntax your using to making the functional SSH connection and how are you mapping the share drive?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using the command ssh sambauser@192.168.0.136
That's on cmd.
Regarding how I'm mapping the share drive, I tried using the "Map network drive" from Windows Explorer and also just pasting \\192.168.0.136\DISK1 in the address of file explorer. In both situations the exact same problem happens.

Comment: I can see in the log that the bad account  is `[MicrosoftAccount]\[sambauser]@[LENOVO-YOGA-730]`. I think that there's no chance that a Microsoft account will work with Ubuntu. Try using `name-of-Ubuntu-computer\Samba-user-name` - what account is then used in the log?

Comment: What happens on Windows 11 File Explorer  \\192.168.0.136\sambashare and authenticate with Ubuntu username and password. That is working here.  I am not a Samba expert. My Windows 11 machine has a Microsoft Account.

Comment: @FeelTheNoise Can you add the log for when another computer successfully connects so we can see if there is any significant difference?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I edited the question and added the log from the other computer. Seems like there are more steps involved. Thank you for giving attention to my question!

Answer (score 1):

By doing some trial and error found the following:

In CMD:

```
E:\>NET USE Z: \\x.x.x.x\sharename youruserpassword /PERSISTENT:NO /USER:yourusername
Error de sistema 67.
```

---

Upgraded Samba to version 4.19.4, I had a look on man smb.conf and made the following changes (since it was configured for SMB2):

```
[global]

workgroup = BLUECROSS
client min protocol = SMB3
client max protocol = SMB3
client smb encrypt = required
client signing = required
server min protocol = SMB3
server max protocol = SMB3
ntlm auth = ntlmv2-only
```

---

It works now:

```
E:\>NET USE Z: \\x.x.x.x\sharename youruserpassword /PERSISTENT:NO /USER:yourusername
Se ha completado el comando correctamente.


E:\>DIR Z:
 El volumen de la unidad Z es sharename
 El número de serie del volumen es: 3C72-71F2

 Directorio de Z:\

12/01/2024  10:28 p. m.    <DIR>          .
12/01/2024  10:28 p. m.    <DIR>          ..
14/12/2023  09:49 p. m.    <DIR>          Documents
14/12/2023  10:34 p. m.    <DIR>          Downloads
10/01/2024  12:09 a. m.    <DIR>          Music
07/03/2022  01:06 p. m.    <DIR>          Pictures
12/05/2023  07:43 p. m.    <DIR>          Videos
               0 archivos              0 bytes
               7 dirs  537,922,781,184 bytes libres

E:\>NET USE Z: /DELETE
Z: se ha eliminado.
```

---

Oher Settings on your Win11 that might help, I had these settings beforehand:

Configuration, Network & internet, Properties: Private (not public) Configuration, Network & internet, Avanced network settings, Advanced Shared settings: All Networks: 128 bit encryption

---

Answer (score -2):

See 3.b from this article, https://seamusdemora.github.io/PiFormulae/FileShare.html

In short, you need to create a password for Samba, for example:
$ sudo smbpasswd -a pi
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password: